# Run selenium Tests in MS loadTest (MS Enterprise )(Azure Devops)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, load-testing, web-performance

Hello fellow developers,

I have created a selenium headless browser test in c# using the MS testing framework (TestClass , TestMethod, etc). I am also using a ChromeDriver for the tests instead of PhantomJSDriver.

All is good and all my tests run locally but when I add them to the test mix of a LoadTest in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterpise Edition and look at the live metrics while the load test is running I get no activity from the load tests. Has anyone else experience this?

Is there a work around or other tools I should look into( I know there is Jmeter but I'm not entirely on board with switching everything to java).

i would post error logs and etc but there are none that I know of .